# Remove placeholders using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code and I want to remove placeholder.

```
<div class="myclass">
  <p><a href="http:[Sitename]">[Sitetile]</a>[change this too]someothercontent</p>
 </div>
```

and I want to change the above markup to this with some event using jQuery:

```
<div class="otherclass">
  <p><a href="http:yahoo.com">changemaincontent</a>changesomeothercontent</p>
</div>
```

Comment: placeholder is an attribute for form element.

Comment: Where is the placeholder that you're trying to remove?

Comment: Placeholder is an attribute for _input_ text elements, not forms. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp There is no placeholder in OP's code indeed.

Comment: Read on jQuery's [attr](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) and [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/). Also, [regex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

Answer (score 1):

Create an object with the index named as the part you want to replace (inside the brackets) and assign the value to it. Then use the `$.each`-function to iterate over the object and replace the values in the html with the one from the object. After that assign the new html-string to your element.

```
var change = {
    'Sitename': 'yahoo.com',
    'Sitetile': 'changemaincontent',
    'change this too': 'change'
};

var $elem = $('.myclass > p'); //cache the element
var html =$elem.html(); //get the html-string

$.each(change, function(index, value){ //iterate over the object

     html =  html.replace('[' + index + ']', value); //replace the values

});

$elem.html(html); //assign the new html-string
```

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vt6jz0os/)**

**Reference**

[.replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

[$.each()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)

[.html()](https://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: if i want to change [change this too] in p tag then how can i change this too

Comment: @Sourabh added this to my answer

Answer (score 0):

you need to put `someothercontent` in `<span>`
**HTML**

```
<div class="myclass">
  <p>
      <a href="http:google.com">maincontent</a>
      <span>someothercontent</span>
    </p>
 </div>
```

**Script**

```
$('.myclass').find('a').text('changemaincontent');
$('.myclass').find('span').text('changesomeothercontent');
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/byLt39m4/)

Comment: i want to find [site] tag and replace with some content

Comment: @Sourabh which `[site] tag` ? please edit your question to make this clear

Comment: @Sourabh if i understood correctly you are telling about link title ( name of the link  )

Comment: Try the first code it works for changing the title of the link ( name of the link )

Comment: @ Sourabh first you need to put `someothercontent` in a `span` like in the `answer ` now what you want to change??

Answer (score 0):

You can try some thing like this !!!

```
<<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <title></title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div id='link'><a href='javascript:open_fun()'>OPEN</a></div>
 </body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function close_fun() {
    document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:open_fun()'>OPEN</a>";
 }
 function open_fun() {
    document.getElementById('link').innerHTML = "<a href='javascript:close_fun()'>CLOSE</a>";
 }
</script>
```

Hope this helps !!!